# How to stop IntelliJ from jumping to a subcategory in run console

Tags: intellij-idea

I hope I can explain my specific annoyance clearly enough:

Quite some time ago, IntelliJ introduced a feature in the run console to parse the content of the output and would try to print a nice tree structure on the left. However, its default behavior of jumping to the error was very annoying. To illustrate my point:

[image: Start run]

When it starts normally, the full console output is available in the right panel. However, when things happen, or, in my case of `gradle run`, when I simply stop it, IntelliJ would jump to the specific block of output only with the error:

[image]

Note, in the second screenshot, that there is no scroll bar on the right side of the right panel, and thus I cannot scroll up to view the actual run logs. I have to click the left panel's top element in the tree to be able to view all logs.

The locking to a specific block of output is nice to have, but I am happy without it too, as before it was introduced. But the default jumping to that block is annoying and irritating. Almost in all cases I started and ended a run like this, I have to click the left panel to view the whole log -- this "Build cancelled" error block is of no use at all. And when it's jumping to an actual exception, majority of the time I'd need to look around its context for the cause, which requires me to re-orient myself in the log flow where the block was at. This is very counter productive for me.

I have been assuming IntelliJ should provide an option to either not jump to the error by default (leaving the full log available in the right panel), or to disable the whole console output parsing as a whole.

I have not been able to locate a setting for either of this. Does anyone know if that's possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We are working to fix that. Please vote and follow https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-241844